# Pip: install dependencies as editable

Tags: python, git, deployment, pip, package

I have an in-house Python application that deploys as a collection of packages, and I need a way for a developer to quickly check out all of these packages as editable source, so that the entire application can be edited in situ, and changes in all packages easily pushed back to the original git server. In addition, the application needs to be deployable as traditional packages by a non-developer.

Say I have a top-level package that has a `setup.py` looking like this:

```
# ...
setup(name="Foo",
      # ...
      url="https://mygitserver.com/Foo",
      install_requires=[
          "Bar>=0.0.1",
      ],
      dependency_links=["git+https://mygitserver.com/Bar@0.0.1#egg=Bar-0.0.1",],
      # ...
  )
```

I can install this package as *editable* with the following command:

```
pip3 install -e git+https://git@mygitserver.com/Foo#egg=Foo --process-dependency-links
```

This will create a directory `src/foo` and populate it with the source code for **`Foo`** checked out from the git server. This is good.

The dependency, `Bar`, is also retrieved from the git server, but *it is not installed as editable*. `pip3 freeze` just shows it as a regular installed package called `Bar`, so the git URL is also lost.

Is there a way to intervene somehow and have pip install some (not necessarily all) dependencies as editable? Or will I need to use a `requirements.txt` in this case? If I have to use `requirements.txt`, how do I also ensure these dependencies are installed normally when deployed by a non-developer?

I know that pip > 10 is meant to do away with `dependency_links` however for the moment I'm stuck with pip 9.0.2. I'm using Python 3.5. I'm targeting an embedded platform that makes it difficult to change these, so these versions are what I'm working with for the moment. If pip >= 10 can do something new to help in this area then I can look into upgrading, it's just not trivial to do on this system.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply `pip install -e <Bar-URL>` before anything and then, when you install `Foo`, pip would figure out the dependency was already installed. Both would be editable.

Comment: Yes, that will work, but it's not very scalable. Please consider the situation where there are many such dependencies, specified in `setup.py` - this method will work but first I'll need pip to determine the URLs for each dependency. I can do this by parsing `setup.py`'s `install_requires` and matching with `dependency_links` but this is tedious. In the case of a non-developer, perhaps an automated system, it would need to work out all of these dependencies and then install each one itself, something that pip would normally do. For a simple project like my example it would work fine though.

Comment: Yes, it's not, but you said you do not want all dependencies editable, just some. I understand you want them customized, each dev could install them differently. In that case, I think it's the best you could do.

Comment: Yeah, good point, I don't want all of the dependencies, just a subset, which means I'm going to have to explicitly specify them somewhere. I think you're right - the best I can do is a custom script to pre-install all the editable packages.